# Automapper returns reference to the same object when mapping sequences to arrays

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`, which maps sequence items and returns an array of clones:

```
public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    public static T[] MapToArray<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<T[]>(sequence);
    }
}
```

Here's code sample, whose behavior is weird from my point:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<SomeClass, SomeClass>();
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        // clone list members and store them into array
        var list = new List<SomeClass>
        {
            new SomeClass { MyProperty = 1 },
            new SomeClass { MyProperty = 2 },
        };

        // works fine
        var array = list.MapToArray();

        // let's map array again
        var newArray = array.MapToArray();

        // ...and ensure, that new array was created;
        // this fails, because Automapper returns reference to the same array
        Debug.Assert(array != newArray);
```

It seems to me, that last result is wrong. While I'm expecting, that mapper will create new array of clones, it just returns the reference to the same array.

Is this documented elsewhere or this is a bug?

Comment: What version of AutoMapper do you have?

Comment: This is reproduced either with 3.2.1 (real project) or 3.3.1 (test project) versions.

Comment: This is a bug. Can you log this issue in GitHub and add a link back to this SO issue? I'll update in both places when fixed.

Comment: Sure, in a couple of days. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @JimmyBogard: sorry for the delay, here's the link to issue at GitHub: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/689

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this isn't a bug - when AutoMapper sees two objects that are assignable, it will simply assign them. If you want to override that behavior, create a map between the two collection types.