# Automapper: How to map a hierarchy in Dictionary

Tags: c#, automapper

In my program, I represent dynamic objects by using Dictionary, like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Values { get; set; }

    public MyObject()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public int InternalAndUnneeded {get;set;} // I don't want to expose it
}
```

These object can cave properties of any type, including the very type of MyObject.
And I want to project the whole hierarchy to the new hierarchy of `MyObjectDto`:

```
public class MyObjectDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Values { get; set; }
}
```

I wrote a simple test:

```
    [Test]
    public void HierarchicalTest()
    {
        MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(c => {
            c.CreateMap<MyObject, MyObjectDto>();
        });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        // prepare: Order references Customer
        MyObject customer = new MyObject();
        customer.Values.Add("FirstName", "John");
        customer.Values.Add("LastName", "Doe");
        customer.Values.Add("Age", 38);

        MyObject order = new MyObject();
        order.Values.Add("Title", "Nails, 1000 items");
        order.Values.Add("Total", 890.50m);
        order.Values.Add("Customer", customer);

        MyObjectDto dto = mapper.Map<MyObjectDto>(order);

        Assert.That(dto, Is.TypeOf<MyObjectDto>());
        Assert.That(dto.Values["Customer"], Is.TypeOf<MyObjectDto>());
    }
```

But it fails on the second assertion saying:

> Expected `PublicAPI.Unit.Tests.MyObjectDto` But was `PublicAPI.Unit.Tests.MyObject`

Basically it only translates the top-level object, but the objects stored as values in the dictionary are not translated. How to make Automapper project the tree at full depth?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automapper returns reference to the same object when mapping sequences to arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874357/automapper-returns-reference-to-the-same-object-when-mapping-sequences-to-arrays)

Comment: Not relevant. I don't need a clone of the source object, I need it to be transformed.

Comment: The point is that `MyObject.Values` is fully assignable to `MyObjectDto.Values` as the types matches. There is no need to convert anything. Maybe you need to provide a custom value resolver to convert the dictionary as well.

Comment: That doesn't apply for the dictionary itself. It is a collection, so it's copied. But it does apply for that inner object. All AM knows is that you're mapping object to object. And that mapping is indeed a trivial assignment. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).